# Content script function as event handler for page element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension. I have a content script in which I add a button to the document on the page the extension is running on, and I want to handle its click event with a function defined in the content script.

```
var parameter = "value extracted from the page";
var onclick = "onclick='myHandler(\"" + parameter + "\")'";
var button = "<span><button " + onclick + "></button></span>";
$(button).insertAfter("#element");
```

However, when I click the button, I get the error that the function is not defined. It seems to me that the content script operates in a different scope than the scripts on the page itself. The latter do not access anything declared in the global scope of the content script.

It occured to me that I could inject the function code and all necessary variables to the page as well (insert a script tag containing the function in a similar fashion as the button) and then access the result from the content script, but it seems like a "hack" to me and I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

Comment: Simply register the event listener explicitly via jQuery click method of the element after you add its html.

Comment: Wow, how did I not think of that... and it's working. Could you please elaborate why this works, and why the other method doesn't?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: In general, your go to solution for event handlers should *not* be using HTML `on*` attributes. You should be defining your event handlers using `addEventListener`, or the various jQuery methods (e.g. `$('.foo').on()`. Using HTML event attributes, or `element.on*` properties is an easy way to have problems.